# $f:X\times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ product measurable if separately measurable and semicontinuous?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a measure space and let $(Y,\mathcal{B})$ be a separable metric space (can assume Polish if necessary) with Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$.

Suppose $f:X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $f(x,\cdot)$ is upper semicontinuous for each $x$ and $f(\cdot, y)$ is measurable for each $y$. Can I conclude that $f$ is product measurable? I know this would be true if $f(x,\cdot)$ would be continuous for each $x$, but this doesn't hold for the case I'm interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *On the Semicontinuity in Product Spaces* by
Antonio J.B. LOPES-PINTO and Diana Aldea MENDES,
it is cited that Sierpinski, in *Funkcje przedstawialne analityczne*, (which I cannot read) constructed a real function  on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is separately upper semicontinuous in both coordinates, but not product measurable. Such a function shows the answer to my question is NO.

Comment: Nice research. Did you find an electronic version of the article? I just tried to google it and did not come up with anything.

Comment: @PhoemueX, use scholar.google.com. https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0201222.pdf

Comment: Thanks! But what I was referring to (which was really not discernible from your side, sorry) was the paper by Sierpinski. Since even if it is in polish, one might possibly still be able to understand the construction - I once read parts of a french math book, although I don't speak french :)

Comment: @PhoemueX sorry for assuming you don't know how to google. I also cannot find an online copy of the Sierpinski paper, in any language.